# C$^*$-Algebra Beginner's Questions

Tags: c-star-algebras

I am starting with $C^*$ algebras. There are some notations that I don't understand. Please help me.

1. What does the identity representation of $C^*$ algebras mean?
2. Let $A$ be $C^*$ algebra generated by the irreducible operator A and the identity. may be  representation is also irreducible?
3. For the operator $T$, then $T^{(n)}$ means that?
4. For the Hilbert space, the notation $H^{(n)}$ means that?
   Sorry if it is too easy for readers. I'm new in this area.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your C$^*$-algebra is already represented inside some $B(H)$, then the identity map (i.e. "doing nothing") is the identity representation.
2. If a represented C$^*$-algebra contains an irreducible operator, then it is of course irreducible.
3. $H^{(n)}$ is the direct sum of $n$ copies of $H$.
4. $T^{(n)}$ is the operator in $B(H^{(n)})$ that acts by $T^{(n)}(h_1,\ldots,h_n)=(Th_1,\ldots,Th_n)$.

Comment: If $T_i$, $i \in N$ is irreducible then may be the direct sum $\sum_{i\in N}T_i$ also is irreducible?

Comment: No. That fails even in dimension one: $1,2,3$ are each irreducible on $\mathbb C$, but $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$ is not irreducible in $M_3 (\mathbb C) $.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. If the direct sum $H=H_1 + H_2$ such that $T$ is completely reducible then may be $T|_{H_1}$ is also completely reducible.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just form the definition of completely reducible, the operator is completely reducible when restricted to any subspace.

Comment: It looks the same of irreducible operators?

Comment: Yes, because if an operator is reducible, then so it any amplification of it.

Comment: If $T$ is irreducible on $H$ then $T^{(n)}$ is also irreducible on $H^{(n)}$, isn't it?

Comment: Not at all. Same as before, $1$ is irreducible on $\mathbb C$ but $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is not irreducible on $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: I am reading a theorem on the structure of opreators, which says that if $T$ is a bounded linear operator then we have the direct sum $T=T_0+T_1^{(n_1)}+...+T_i^{(n_i)}+...$. I guess $T_0$ is completely reducible, $T_i^{(n_i)}$ is irreducible. Is it correct?

Comment: If you don't say what $T_0,T_1,\ldots$ are it is impossible to say anything.

Comment: $T_j \in L(H_j)$.

Comment: That is still meaningless. The Theorem you are quoting is likely a multiplicity theorem, but just writing a decomposition without saying what conditions the components are supposed to satisfy is meaningless.

Comment: If there exists an unitary operator $U$ such that $UT^{(m)}=T^{(n)}U$ for irreducible operator $T$, how to prove $m=n$.

Comment: @Martin Argerami, is the identity representation be non-degenerate?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have for example $A=A_0\oplus 0\subset B(H)\oplus B(H)$, then the identity representation is degenerate (since $A(H\oplus H)=H\oplus 0$).